# linker error hidden symbol `__popcountdi2'

Tags: gcc, linker

I'm building an application that results in the following error:

```
hidden symbol `__popcountdi2' in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/libgcc.a(_popcountsi2.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This can be fixed with '-shared-libgcc' linked option, but I would like to understand the issue and what is causing it. Also it appears that others don't observe the issue, although we all run the same Linux distribution (Fedora 20), the same tools and libraries (gcc-4.8.3-7.fc20.x86_64, libgcc-4.8.3-7.fc20.x86_64 and binutils-2.23.88.0.1-13.fc20.x86_64), so I suspect there's something wrong with my platform, may be some libs are missing etc.

I would appreciate if someone could give hints to understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I hit a similar issue with "unknown symbol: __popcountdi2" when preloading a statically linked dynamic library into a test tool, both compiled with "--coverage" to gather code coverage. I solved it by using '-shared-libgcc' only for the test tool as well.